# Login com facebook em javaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Estou fazendo login com fb somente com js utilizando o facebook sdk. A parte do login esta fazendo certinho, mas por algum motivo só me retorna nome e id. Não esta retornando e-mail e outros atributos que preciso. Meu código

```html
<html>
  <body>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXXXX', // Set YOUR APP ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
      version    : 'v2.3'
    });
 
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Connected to Facebook";
        //SUCCESS
      }
      else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Failed to Connect";
        //FAILED
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Logged Out";
        //UNKNOWN ERROR
      }
    });
  };

  function Login()
  {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        getUserInfo();
      }
      else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
      }
    },{ scope: 'email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown' });
  }

  function getUserInfo() {
      FB.api('/me?fields=name,email,gender,birthday,link', function(response) {
         console.log(response);
         var str = "<b>Name</b> : " + response.name + "<br>";
         str += "<b>Link: </b>" + response.link + "<br>";
         str += "<b>Username:</b> " + response.username + "<br>";
         str += "<b>id: </b>" + response.id + "<br>";
         str += "<b>Email:</b> " + response.email + "<br>";
         str += "<input type='button' value='Get Photo' onclick='getPhoto();'/>";
         str += "<input type='button' value='Logout' onclick='Logout();'/>";
         document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = str;
      }, { scope: 'email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown' });
 }
  
  
  function getPhoto() {
    FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
      var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+=str;
    });
  }

  function Logout() {
    FB.logout(function(){document.location.reload();});
  }

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }

    js      = d.createElement('script');
    js.id   = id; js.async = true;
    js.src  = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div align="center">
  <h2 style="font-family:VERDANA">SmartPromos Login FB</h2>
  <div id="status">
     <br/>
    <img src="http://donatetab.firstgiving.com/images/fb-login-button.png" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="Login()"/>
  </div>

  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <div id="message">
  
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As vezes o e-mail não está público e isso impossibilita de ser mostrado. Assim como cidade e estado.

Comment: hmmm entendi, eu acho que não foi esse caso, porque estou fazendo no android tbm e la no mobile ele retorna um json com o email e outros atributos.

Answer (score 1):

Entendi.

No final da `}` do `FB.login`que está em `function Login()`, coloque:

`,{ scope: 'email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown' }`

Coloque `user_about_me` no `scope`.

Veja do jeito que fiz um tempo atrás, funcionou:

[image: Exemplo]

Está uma burocracia fazer uso do Login do Facebook agora. Já vou avisando.

Tem que ter SSL na hospedagem.

Isto é, `https`.

Comment: coloquei, mas nao funcionou só traz nome e id

Comment: Eu confundi de função, editei meu código. Leia de novo.

Comment: Alterei do jeito que vc fez no metodo getUserInfo mas nada tbm

Comment: É mo método `Login()`.

Comment: Fiz a alteração no método login e editei minha pergunta, mas ainda não traz.

Comment: Bom, você está usando uma versão antiga da API do Facebook, a 2.3, sem **oAuth**. Pode ser isso. Mas você falou que no seu android retorna o JSON com os dados... e pode tirar no médito `getUserInfo()` o scope.

Comment: Sim eu acho que é a versão antiga mesmo, disponibiliza seu código desse jeito com o Canvas eu vou implementar as alterações no meu. No android eu fiz diferente mas tbm preciso fazer na versão web e só acho coisas com essa api antiga

Comment: Esse canvas aí é frescura minha, é que eu fiz umas bagaça de efeito na página, por isso o canvas.

Comment: Entendi, bom vou dar uma procurada no no login com oAuth, valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Encontrei o erro, vou editar minha pergunta e colocar a alteração. O que eu acrescentei foi  FB.api('/me?fields=name,email,gender,birthday,link'